# CSS :active moving other img down

Tags: html, css

I want to display full image when an user clicks on it, but without moving everything, simulating a modal that shows full image on the screen above every other images, like when you click a Facebook image post.

I've tried with `z-index`, using `position` but I cannot make it work.

Yes, I only have to use HTML and CSS.

```css
.container-fluid {
  padding: 0em 10em;
}

.h1 {
  margin-bottom: 35px;
  box-shadow: 0 5px 5px -5px #333;
  color: #70aeb6;
}

a.photo-container>img {
  margin-bottom: 50px;
}

a.photo-container {
  text-decoration: none;
}

a.photo-container:active>img {
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="es-MX">

<head>
  <meta charset="UTF-8">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
  <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="ie=edge">
  <link rel="shortcut icon" type="image/png" href="https://via.placeholder.com/16x16" />
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.0.0/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-Gn5384xqQ1aoWXA+058RXPxPg6fy4IWvTNh0E263XmFcJlSAwiGgFAW/dAiS6JXm" crossorigin="anonymous">
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="css/styles.css">
  <title>Gallery</title>
</head>

<div class="container-fluid">
  <div class="h1 text-center">
    Classmates gallery
  </div>

  <div class="d-inline">
    <a href="#" class="photo-container">
      <img src="https://via.placeholder.com/300x200">
    </a>
    <a href="#" class="photo-container">
      <img src="https://via.placeholder.com/300x200">
    </a>
    <a href="#" class="photo-container">
      <img src="https://via.placeholder.com/300x200">
    </a>
    <a href="#" class="photo-container">
      <img src="https://via.placeholder.com/300x200">
    </a>
    <a href="#" class="photo-container">
      <img src="https://via.placeholder.com/300x200">
    </a>
    <a href="#" class="photo-container">
      <img src="https://via.placeholder.com/300x200">
    </a>
    <a href="#" class="photo-container">
      <img src="https://via.placeholder.com/300x200">
    </a>
    <a href="#" class="photo-container">
      <img src="https://via.placeholder.com/300x200">
    </a>
  </div>
</div>

</html>
```

Comment: "I've tried with z-index, using position" - please show what you have tried. Make sure to include all relevant code **in the question itself**

Answer (score 1):

Maybe try using css transform. Here is an example, try adding these lines to your code:

```
a.photo-container {
    transition: transform .2s ease-in-out; 
}

a.photo-container:active>img {
  transform: scale(1.4);
}
```

```css
.container-fluid {
  padding: 0em 10em;
}

.h1 {
  margin-bottom: 35px;
  box-shadow: 0 5px 5px -5px #333;
  color: #70aeb6;
}

a.photo-container>img {
  margin-bottom: 50px;
  transition: transform .2s ease-in-out;
}

a.photo-container {
  text-decoration: none;
  position: relative;
  display: inline-block;
}

a.photo-container:active>img {
  transform: scale(1.4);
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="es-MX">

<head>
  <meta charset="UTF-8">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
  <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="ie=edge">
  <link rel="shortcut icon" type="image/png" href="https://via.placeholder.com/16x16" />
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.0.0/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-Gn5384xqQ1aoWXA+058RXPxPg6fy4IWvTNh0E263XmFcJlSAwiGgFAW/dAiS6JXm" crossorigin="anonymous">
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="css/styles.css">
  <title>Gallery</title>
</head>

<div class="container-fluid">
  <div class="h1 text-center">
    Classmates gallery
  </div>

  <div class="d-block">
    <a href="#" class="photo-container">
      <img src="https://via.placeholder.com/300x200">
    </a>
    <a href="#" class="photo-container">
      <img src="https://via.placeholder.com/300x200">
    </a>
    <a href="#" class="photo-container">
      <img src="https://via.placeholder.com/300x200">
    </a>
    <a href="#" class="photo-container">
      <img src="https://via.placeholder.com/300x200">
    </a>
    <a href="#" class="photo-container">
      <img src="https://via.placeholder.com/300x200">
    </a>
    <a href="#" class="photo-container">
      <img src="https://via.placeholder.com/300x200">
    </a>
    <a href="#" class="photo-container">
      <img src="https://via.placeholder.com/300x200">
    </a>
    <a href="#" class="photo-container">
      <img src="https://via.placeholder.com/300x200">
    </a>
  </div>
</div>

</html>
```

Comment: Yes, it's kind of what I want to do, but when user clicks on image, I want to display it fully, as a modal
I don't know if I explain myself... however, your example gave an idea, let me try

Comment: Do you want a modal with just css?

Comment: @BryanArreola you should mention that you want to display it as a modal in your question. That is quite different to what you have actually asked.

Comment: Then shall I close this question? It's ok for me.